# How can I get JSON data into my ejs template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to display JSON data but I have this error. Can anyone help me with this please?

> Error -- > Unexpected token ; in
>   "/home/ubuntu/workspace/project_guest_book/views/pages/posts.ej

The code that causing error is below:

```
<%  var post = require(__dirname +"/userPosts.json")
        var result= %> 
          <table>
            <% for (var i=0; i<post.length; i++){
               result += %>
                 <tr>
                    <th><% post[i].Name+ %></th>
                    <td><% post[i].Post %></td>
                 </tr>
            <% } %>
          <table>
```

Comment: You can't output HTML *into* a variable like that, what you end up with is `var result= ` without a given value, which is a syntax error.

Comment: But even if I provide a value I still have the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJS is not expected to be used the way you are trying to use it.

Think about the ejs template as markup with embedded javascript which compiles to a function that can be provided with the required data and which gives you back the final html.

So you do not have to worry about storing the intermediate markup in variables or concatenation of html fragments.

Checkout the implementation in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fobLrok5/):

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
  <table>
    <% for (var i=0; i< posts.length; i++){ %>
      <tr>
        <th><%= posts[i].Name %></th>
        <td><%= posts[i].Post %></td>
      </tr>
    <% } %>
  <table>
</script>
```

-

```
// This can be loaded from an external file:
var posts = [{
  Name: "Post1", Post: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
}, {
  Name: "Post2", Post: "Lorem ipsum consecteuter adpiscing elit"
}]

var compiledTemplate = ejs.compile(document.getElementById('template').innerText)

console.log(compiledTemplate({ posts: posts }))
```

Comment: Thanks, for clear response with codes. Its now easy to understand what I was doing wrong.